# Manual Map using Array.prototype, I don't understand where things are being passed around (JS)

Tags: javascript, callback, this, array.prototype.map

I'm just very very confused with this code.

How does 'callback' somehow know we are referring to the array we want to manipulate (line 4)?
The parameter 'callback' is never even passed anything, so how does the computer know to access the array's elements from callback? (line 9).
I understand that the 'this[i]' is referring to the elements, but where is the array actually being passed into this function?

Also lines 17 - 19:

As s.myMap is already a function, why do we then have to specify 'function(item)..' ?

Shouldn't it just be s.myMap() because it's a function?
What does 'item' represent on lines 17?

It's really frustrating, sorry if I'm not clear enough with the question.

```
// The global variable
const s = [23, 65, 98, 5];

Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  
  // Only change code below this line
  for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){ 
    newArray.push(callback(this[i]));
  }

  // Only change code above this line
  return newArray;
};


const new_s = s.myMap(function(item) {
  return item * 2;
});





console.log(new_s);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/78t5v.png

Comment: Please add code as text instead of an image

Comment: Line 9: `this[i]` is passed to the component, not retrieved from the component. `this` refers to the array because of `prototype`. `item` at line `17` is exactly the same as `this[i]` at line `9`

Comment: Agree with @KonradLinkowski on both points.  On the last question, myMap is a function that *takes a function as it's parameter*. The function on the last few lines is that parameter

Comment: Thanks guys. So the 'callback' parameter, what actually is that?